# Convert dates list dimensions from Mx2 to 2Mx1

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a 13x2 list of dates. I need to turn it into a 26x1 list, with the second column moved below the first, so I may then sort it by date. How can this be done? Its gotta be simple but can't figure it out. Thanks very much.

```
#13x2 list of dates:
nfpdates1 <- list(structure(c(10963, 10991, 11019, 11054, 11082, 11110, 11145,11173, 11201, 11236, 11264, 11299, 10961), class = "Date"), structure(c(13518,13546, 13581, 13609, 13637, 13665, 13700, 13728, 13763, 13791,13819, 13854, 13517), class = "Date")) 

#This is what nfpdates1 looks like: 
[[1]]
 [1] "2000-01-07" "2000-02-04" "2000-03-03" "2000-04-07" "2000-05-05"
 [6] "2000-06-02" "2000-07-07" "2000-08-04" "2000-09-01" "2000-10-06"
[11] "2000-11-03" "2000-12-08" "2000-01-05"

[[2]]
 [1] "2007-01-05" "2007-02-02" "2007-03-09" "2007-04-06" "2007-05-04"
 [6] "2007-06-01" "2007-07-06" "2007-08-03" "2007-09-07" "2007-10-05"
[11] "2007-11-02" "2007-12-07" "2007-01-04"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`,

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(nfpdates1, as.data.frame))
#X[[i]]
#1: 2000-01-07
#2: 2000-02-04
#3: 2000-03-03
#4: 2000-04-07
#5: 2000-05-05
#6: 2000-06-02
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R implementation:

```
outputDates <- do.call('cbind',nfpdates1)
class(outputDates) <- "Date"
outputDate
    [1] "2000-01-07" "2000-02-04" "2000-03-03" "2000-04-07" "2000-05-05"
    [6] "2000-06-02" "2000-07-07" "2000-08-04" "2000-09-01" "2000-10-06"
    [11] "2000-11-03" "2000-12-08" "2000-01-05" "2007-01-05" "2007-02-02"
    [16] "2007-03-09" "2007-04-06" "2007-05-04" "2007-06-01" "2007-07-06"
    [21] "2007-08-03" "2007-09-07" "2007-10-05" "2007-11-02" "2007-12-07"
    [26] "2007-01-04"
```

This should do.